# Proper way of creating an array or pushing into it if it already exists

Tags: javascript, arrays

In my code I have an element, and I want to have it in an array: either the array already exists and then I push my element, or it doesn't and in that case I create the array with this only element:

```
if (arr) {
  arr.push(elt);
} else {
  arr = [elt];
}
```

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. I looked into `spreading` and `nullish coalescing operator`, but I didn't find any correct syntax.
Does anybody have an idea on how I could write my lines with a nicer syntax?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `arr = (arr || []).concat([elt])`?

Comment: @Nick your answer is correct except for the square brackets around elt.

Comment: I think his answer is really correct, no?

Comment: @Nice `array.concat()` concatenates two arrays. For his answer to work it must wrap the new element in an array.

Comment: @NiceBooks if `elt` is a simple value, sure, but otherwise, no, the `[]` are required. Compare `[].concat([1, 2])` with `[].concat([[1, 2]])`

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular the argument of concat need not be an array.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: spreading and nullish coalescing
[...a??[]].concat(["test"])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the expression `arr || []` to return an array which is either `arr` if `arr` is defined already or `[]` otherwise. Then you can simply [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) the new value to it:

```js
arr = (arr || []).concat([elt])
```

Note the new value needs to be enclosed in `[]` to prevent `elt` values which are arrays from being flattened.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an array exists by testing if it is false-y. Thus, you can create an array if it doesn't already exist with

```
arr = (arr || []);
```

From there you can just push your new element:

```
arr = (arr || []);
arr.push(elt);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below code:

```
if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
  arr.push(elt);
  //or can use spread operator
  arr = [...arr, elt];//this should work if I am not wrong
} else {
  arr = [elt];
}
```

It is somewhat similar but I guess it should work fine and is a general pattern.

Comment: Actually I was looking for something shorter and more readable :)